# Haar Cascades Eye Detection Does Not Work On Python Django Webpage?

Tags: python, html, django

I try to display live stream webcam on webpage using Django with OpenCV eye detection.

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imutils
import cv2,os,urllib.request
import numpy as np
from django.conf import settings

eyes_detection = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haar/haarcascade_eye.xml')

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        eyes_detected = eyes_detection.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)
        for (x, y, w, h) in eyes_detected:
            cv2.rectangle(image, pt1=(x, y), pt2=(x + w, y + h), color=(0,255,0), thickness=2)
        frame_flip = cv2.flip(image,1)
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_flip)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

The video stream will not be displayed with the code above, however, the video can be displayed if I remove line 20-23(gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY). How can I display the video stream with eye detection on the webpage?

Below is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http.response import StreamingHttpResponse
from main.tryhaar import VideoCamera
import cv2

def gen(tryhaar):
    while True:
        frame = tryhaar.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

def video_feed(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Comment: did you try to add code line-by-line? First add only line 20, next 21, etc. And you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Don't you get error message when you run it in console?

Comment: all code seems OK - I don't see where can be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All problem can make file `.xml`. You need correct path to this file.

There is special variable with path to folder with all files `.xml` - `cv2.data.haarcascades` - and you can use it with filename (without `haar/`) to create correct path.

```
eyes_detection = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

or using `os.path.join`

```
eyes_detection = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, 'haarcascade_eye.xml'))
```

Comment: OMG Thank you very much, it does work this way. It is able to detect the eye. Thank you very much. In my terminal it says:
[ WARN:3] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:3] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
I have no idea what this is but it worked.

Comment: I never saw this type of error. Maybe it is problem with hardware. Create new question on new page - you will have more space for code and description. And new people wil see it.